# Invalid Request Origin after Python post request

Tags: python, html, post, get, python-requests

I've been trying to write a program which gets my school timetable which is locked behind a login screen, however when I run my python script I am greeted by:

```
Sorry, we are unable to complete this request

An error occured while submitting the form:

Invalid Request Origin
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```
import requests

login_url =     'https://WEBSITE/login?page=%2Fhomepage'
timetable_url = 'https://WEBSITE/timetable'

payload = {
    'username': 'USERNAME', 
    'password': 'PASSWORD'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(login_url, data=payload, verify = True)
    r = session.get(timetable_url)
    print (post.text)
```

And this is the html from the login page:

```
<div id="content">
   <form id="login" method="post" action="/login?page=%2Flogin%2F">
      <input type="hidden" name="page" value="/login/" />
      <div class="row collapse">
         <div class="small-12 column">
            <div class="logo">
               <img src="/images/logo.php?logo=skin_logo_login&size=normal" alt="Schoolbox" />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="small-12 column">
            <p id="error-msg" class="alert-box alert"></p>
         </div>
         <div class="small-12 column">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row collapse">
         <div class="small-12 column">
            <p><a href="/forgotten-password.php">Forgotten your password?</a></p>
         </div>
         <div class="small-12 column">
            <input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1" />
            <label for="rememberme">Remember me</label>
         </div>
         <div class="small-12 column login-links">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" alt="Login" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

How exactly would I be able to solve this error, or would there be any other more viable solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error `Invalid Request Origin` means that your origin does not match what is restricted by the server. You could try adding the `Origin:` header specifying your `timetable_url`, but it is likely that the page can only be called by another page on the server.